# SQL statements run much slower in Python than command-line SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQL script that creates 2 temp tables, then creates 2 permanent tables based on the temp tables (4 steps). No rows are returned. When that script is run from the command line using
`$ sqlite3 MyDB.db -init Summarize.sql`
it takes less than a minute.
When the SQL is run as a big string in Python (via the SQLite3 standard module)
`connection.executescript("""<contents of Summarize.sql here>""")`
it takes 15 minutes. (The first 3 steps take 1 minute, the last step takes the remaining 14.)

Given that it's the exact same SQL, what could Python be doing that would slow it down so much? How can I speed this up?
(The last step is a `drop table if exists xxx; create table xxx as select ...` It's a join, but it's the same join that the command line runs quickly.) A friend suggested the apsw module, but I'm loathe to switch without strong cause.

Comment: Have you checked that the version of SQLite your Python installation was built against matches the one from your command-line tool?

Comment: That is to say -- look at the `sqlite3.sqlite_version` constant. It's also worth comparing the runtime configuration -- isolation level &c.

Comment: I'm on Windoze 7.  As a python noob, I have a fresh python installation courtesy of Anaconda.  `sqlite3.sqlite_version` is '3.6.21'.  The command-line program (courtesy of Cygwin) `$ sqlite3 -version` returns "3.8.7 2014-10-17 11:24:17".

Comment: Just for fun I tried running the sql from python using the apsw module.  Takes half a minute.  I guess the native sqlite3 module is somehow interposing itself (could it be a commit per row??) in some way.  Hrmph.  This is not an answer, but at least I have a workaround.

Comment: Actually -- if you aren't manually opening a transaction, you could indeed be getting autocommit behavior.

Comment: In general, operating directly on a connection (rather than getting a cursor, opening a transaction within it, etc) is intended more for throwaway functionality where you don't care about the details of implementation, rather than the intended mode of use.

Comment: Also, as you validated above, you _are_ comparing a much newer version of sqlite (3.8.7, from October 2014) against a much older one (3.6.21, from December 2009), so some amount of performance difference is to be expected on that account alone.

Comment: There is not really a "native" SQLite. Both Python's `sqlite3` module and the `apsw` module have a compiled-in copy of the SQLite library; Python's just happens to be much older.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy re Autocommit: Wrapping my code in `begin/end transaction` didn't help, so that must not be it.

Comment: Well, the obvious thing is the version difference. A lot of performance optimizations can happen in five years. If it's that important to you, you can recompile your Python interpreter (and thus its standard library, thereby including sqlite3) against a new version of SQLite.

Comment: You could also build a command-line version of SQLite 3.6.21, and see if you get the same _slow_ performance there, as an easier way to test whether the issue comes down to versioning.

Comment: ...that said, when you say `begin/end transaction`, do you mean `begin transaction` and `end transaction` commands in your SQL, as opposed to making equivalent calls on a Python cursor object? Because you really, really should be using a cursor object (and running your code through that cursor, not through the connection).

Comment: I meant `begin transaction` because it's part of the larger script.  Having said that, I tried using the cursor (vs. the connection), and it did not help.  I'm sticking with apsw for this bit.

Answer (score 0):

Calling SQLite from Python is about 100 times slower versus a command line call in my tests.  Here is a solution. I just output my query to a text file sql.txt and invoke a command line SQLite call from Python:

```
import subprocess
import sys

print subprocess.Popen("sqlite3 reviews.db < sql.txt", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

You can add multiple queries to **sql.txt** and call other files by using `.read filename` command